# R dataframe define column names at creation

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I get monthly price value for the two assets below from Yahoo:

```
if(!require("tseries") | !require(its) ) { install.packages(c("tseries", 'its'));  require("tseries"); require(its) } 
startDate <- as.Date("2000-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")
MSFT.prices = get.hist.quote(instrument="msft", start= startDate,
                               quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                               compression="m", retclass="its")
SP500.prices = get.hist.quote(instrument="^gspc", start=startDate,
                                quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                                compression="m", retclass="its")
```

I want to put these two into a single data frame with specified columnames (Pandas allows this now - a bit ironic since they take the data.frame concept from R). As below, I assign the two time series with names:

```
MSFTSP500.prices <- data.frame(msft = MSFT.prices, sp500= SP500.prices )
```

However, this does not preserve the column names `[msft, snp500]` I have appointed. I need to define column names in a separate line of code:

```
colnames(MSFTSP500.prices) <- c("msft", "sp500")
```

I tried to put `colnames` and `col.names` inside the `data.frame()` call but it doesn't work. How can I define column names while creating the data frame?

I found `?data.frame` very unhelpful...

Comment: @BondedDust That’s invalid R code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fails with an error message indicating no availability of `as.its`. So I added the missing code (which appears to have been successful after two failed attempts.) Once you issue the missing `require()` call you can use `str` to see what sort of object `get.hist.quote` actually returns. It is neither a dataframe nor a zoo object, although it resembles a zoo-object in many ways:

```
> str(SP500.prices)
Formal class 'its' [package "its"] with 2 slots
  ..@ .Data: num [1:180, 1] 1394 1366 1499 1452 1421 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:180] "2000-01-02" "2000-01-31" "2000-02-29" "2000-04-02" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr "AdjClose"
  ..@ dates: POSIXct[1:180], format: "2000-01-02 16:00:00" "2000-01-31 16:00:00" ...
```

If you run `cbind` on those two objects you get a regular matrix with dimnames:

```
> str(cbind(SP500.prices, MSFT.prices)  )
 num [1:180, 1:2] 1394 1366 1499 1452 1421 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:180] "2000-01-02" "2000-01-31" "2000-02-29" "2000-04-02" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "AdjClose" "AdjClose"
```

You will still need to change the column names since there does not seem to be a `cbind.its` that lets you assign column-names. I would caution about using the `data.frame` method, since the object is might get confusing in its behavior:

```
> str( MSFTSP500.prices )
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ AdjClose  :Formal class 'AsIs', 'its' [package ""] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ .S3Class: chr  "AsIs" "its"
 $ AdjClose.1:Formal class 'AsIs', 'its' [package ""] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ .S3Class: chr  "AsIs" "its"
```

The columns are still S4 objects. I suppose that might be useful if you were going to pass them to other `its`-methods but could be confusing otherwise. This might be what you were shooting for:

```
> MSFTSP500.prices <- data.frame(msft = as.vector(MSFT.prices), 
                                 sp500= as.vector(SP500.prices) ,
                           row.names= as.character(MSFT.prices@dates) ) 
> str( MSFTSP500.prices )
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ msft : num  35.1 32 38.1 25 22.4 ...
 $ sp500: num  1394 1366 1499 1452 1421 ...
> head(rownames(MSFTSP500.prices))
[1] "2000-01-02 16:00:00" "2000-01-31 16:00:00" "2000-02-29 16:00:00"
[4] "2000-04-02 17:00:00" "2000-04-30 17:00:00" "2000-05-31 17:00:00"
```

Comment: Actually, if you don't use `its` it falls back to `zoo`. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

MSFT.prices is a zoo object, which seems to be a data-frame-alike, with its own column name which gets transferred to the object. Confer

```
tmp <- data.frame(a=1:10)
b <- data.frame(lost=tmp)
```

which loses the second column name.

If you do

```
MSFTSP500.prices <- data.frame(msft = as.vector(MSFT.prices), 
     sp500=as.vector(SP500.prices))
```

then you will get the colnames you want (though you won't get zoo-specific behaviours). Not sure why you object to renaming columns in a second command, though.

Comment: I think the constructor should cater for initialising the column names. You're right if I do `as.numeric` or `as.vector` I keep the column names, but then lose the row.names, i.e. the index.

Comment: @Zhubarb: I don't think that the authors of 'tseries' wanted you to  use `data.frame`-methods on their data-objects. Internally the `.Data` core is an R-matrix.